# Result of division from two different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have query result from 1 table related with amount of done tickets in company. Second query is time spent on perform this tickets. Results comes from 2 not related tables.

Result 1 comes from:

```
    Count(DISTINCT case_id) AS a
    FROM   booker
```

Result 2 comes from:

```
SELECT sum(TO_NUMBER(LEFT(duration, 2),'99D999') + TO_NUMBER(SUBSTRING(duration, 3,3),'99D999') / 60 + TO_NUMBER(RIGHT(duration, 2),'99D999') / 3600) 
FROM    time_ad
```

Result 1 is number: 120

Result 2 is number: 12,234

I would like to have 1 query that extract results from both queries and devide it.

Any ideas to do it in 1 query?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: TO_NUMBER is not recognized by MySQL or MS SQL Server... ??

Comment: `TO_NUMBER` is an `ORACLE` function not `MySQL` and `MS SQL Server` https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions191.htm.  The TO_NUMBER function can be used in the following versions of Oracle/PLSQL: `Oracle 12c, Oracle 11g, Oracle 10g, Oracle 9i, Oracle 8i`

Comment: sorry for wrong tag. It's redshift database and I was not sure what tags should I choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it directly (not tested, but it should work):

```
SELECT 
(SELECT Count(DISTINCT case_id) AS a FROM booker) /
(SELECT sum(TO_NUMBER(LEFT(duration, 2),'99D999') + TO_NUMBER(SUBSTRING(duration, 3,3),'99D999') / 60 + TO_NUMBER(RIGHT(duration, 2),'99D999') / 3600) 
FROM    time_ad) AS MyResult
```

Comment: @nynek If it works perfectly, mark it as correct answer, please. Thank you